# Karma + PhantomJS + no internet access

Tags: gruntjs, npm, phantomjs, offline, karma-runner

I need to run Karma tests using PhantomJS on a continuous integration server with no internet access. Every build starts from running `npm install --no-registry` and then `grunt`
Grunt Karma is configured for single run (`singleRun: true`)

Everything works well except PhantomJS. Even though phantomjs package is in npm-cache it tries to download actual binary (.exe in my case) directly from **bitbucket.org** and obviously fails due to no inet access.

I tried to pre-install PhantomJS package globally (`npm install -g phantomjs`). Now the binary is resolved in offline mode, tests run pass and pass, everything looks fine but... Karma test suite now never ends (presumably due to PhantomJS never exits) until I hit *Ctrl+C*. (**It only happens when I explicitly install PhantomJS package globally with `npm install -g ...`**. If I'm not doing that and let it to be downloaded from the *BitBucket* automatically it run fine).
The version of PhantomJS is the same in both cases, I double checked.

I tried different versions of PhantomJS (1.9.7, 1.9.6, 1.9.2) and Karma (0.11, 0.10) -- no difference.

Here's my **package.json**:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4",
    "karma": "~0.10",
    "grunt-karma": "~0.6"
}
```

And here's what I see if I run Karma having PhantomJS installed with '-g':

```
> npm install -g phantomjs
Done. Phantomjs binary available at .....
phantomjs@1.9.7-1 C:\Users\.....\npm\node_modules\phantomjs

> karma start --single-run
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.9 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Windows 7)]: Connected on socket JjD-wPAWrUeuz1NBTw02
LOG: 'JQMIGRATE: Logging is active'
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Windows 7): Executed 60 of 60 SUCCESS (0.362 secs / 0.204 secs)
WARN [launcher]: PhantomJS was not killed in 2000 ms, sending SIGKILL.
_
```

(and hangs... After Ctrl+C build is continued)

I don't get why this is happening.

**Questions**

- How is it related to installing phantom package with '-g'?
- What is proper way for configuring environment with no internet access to run Karma tests with PhantomJS?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

According to the [PhantomJS NPM package documentation](https://www.npmjs.org/package/phantomjs) you can set the `PHANTOMJS_CDNURL` environment variable to point to a different (local) HTTP endpoint when you run `npm install`.

```
PHANTOMJS_CDNURL=http://some.server.here/downloads npm install phantomjs
```

The default is https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads.

Also, if you put PhantomJS on your path, it should try to use that.